# Use prolog debug/trace mode without dots?

Tags: debugging, prolog, output, three-dots

To get some prolog answer without dots its possible to use the flag:

```
set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(0)])
```

Is their some similar option to print the entire debug output line by line without dots too?

Answer (score 1):

```
set_prolog_flag(debugger_write_options,[max_depth(0)]),
```